# Django Query duplicated 2 times in generic class based UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Project model

```
class Project(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members")
```

and I am using a classbased Update view to restrict only those users who are members of the project.

```
class ProjectUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ["name"]

    def test_func(self):
        members = self.get_object().members.all()
        if members.contains(self.request.user):
            return True
        return False
```

After looking at the SQL queries through Djang Debug Toolbar, I see the query is duplicated 2 times.
the 1st instance is from this `test_func` and the other instance is from django generic views, how can I resolve the duplicated query issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter the queryset to retrieve only projects where the `request.user` is a member of that `Project`, so:

```
class ProjectUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']

    def get_querset(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(members=self.request.user)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `Project`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`members`</s> relation to `projects`.

Comment: Thanks @Willem your comments are helpful, will update on the ```related_name=..``` part. for the user model, agree in actual code have referenced settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.